# What techniques can be employed to build a low-profile sliding door/wall?

Tags: building

I'm looking to build a sliding door or wall that doesn't use the defacto "sliding door" parts, [2874](https://rebrickable.com/parts/2874) and [4511](https://rebrickable.com/parts/4511).  These parts are almost usable for my design: they are thin and have a built-in stopper when using the corresponding "door rail" parts [32028](https://rebrickable.com/parts/32028) and [4510](https://rebrickable.com/parts/4510).  Unfortunately, they are too tall.

Is there a technique to slide a plate, tile, or panel without resorting to using part [30586](https://rebrickable.com/parts/30586).  I don't think I have the extra width needed by this part in my design.

Comment: What size of door are you looking for? What's the width of the wall?

Comment: @Uli: I'm building a railroad car using a 28x6 plate, so the wall length is constrained to 28 studs.  Wall thickness is 1 stud, so the interior of the car has 4 studs of space.  That said, I have things inside the car and so I was hoping to mount the sliding door on the outside and keep a low profile.  Ideally, the door will be under 5 studs in height.  I can probably increase the height of the car and then use the defacto sliding door, but I was interested to see if other alternatives exist.

Comment: How many studs is the opening in the wall?

Comment: Fairly flexible at this point as I'm trying to see what is possible with the technique.  That said, I would estimate the the opening to be between 4-6 studs.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using "bricks with groove" ?

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=brick%20with%20groove#T=A

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!  These may work, but I would have to orient them so that the studs align horizontally.  I'll have to analyze my design to see if that is feasible.